# SonarQube Analysis Error "Error during SonarQube Scanner execution : Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries"

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am stuck while configuring sonarqube having version 5.6.2 and SonarQube scanner 2.5.1 with maven 3.2.5.  I am having a multi-module java project and I have defined the sonar`.java.binaries=target/classes` but still facing the following error:

> INFO: JavaClasspath initialization INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ INFO: Total time: 33.798s INFO: Final Memory: 75M/3927M INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: Please provide compiled classes of your project with sonar.java.binaries property     at org.sonar.java.JavaClasspath.init(JavaClasspath.java:59)     at org.sonar.java.AbstractJavaClasspath.getElements(AbstractJavaClasspath.java:281)     at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.getJavaClasspath(SonarComponents.java:141)    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.(JavaSquid.java:83)   at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:83)  at org.sonar.batch.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:57)  at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)  at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)  at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)  at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)  at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)  at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)  at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)  at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)  at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)   at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)  at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)  at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)  at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)   at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:67)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:274)   at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:165)     at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:152)     at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:133)  at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:82)   at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:66) ERROR:  ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. Build step 'Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis' marked build as failure Deleting 1 temporary files

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: question is : how to resolve above error?

Answer (score 0):

You are analysing a Java project, for which you are using Maven as a build tool. As a consequence, you shall not be using the SonarQube Scanner (CLI) but the [SonarQube Scanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven).

As explained in the documentation, you simply need to execute:

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar
```

Comment: We are using sonarqube plugin integrated with jenkins for scanning the project. And using Standalone Sonarqube Analysis in Post build Steps.

Comment: This is not what you should do. Please look at the documentation about how to analyse a Maven project with Jenkins: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven